# Enable href navigation after JQuery addclass

Tags: jquery

I need to use jQuery's `addClass` to change the selected anchor tag's style. It is working fine. But after changing the style I want to navigate to a link specified in the `href`. This is not working since I am using `return false;` or `e.preventDefault()`.

Please help me.

The code which I am using is:

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

<div id="navigation" class="right">
    <ul>
        <li id="nav1"><a href="../WebForm1.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li id="nav2"><a href="../AboutUs.aspx"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here the style is applied after clicking the Home link but I want it to navigate to `webform1.aspx` after this.

Comment: Is there a strong reason for not using CSS's `:active` pseudo-class?

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if your `li` tag contains active class, if it has then go to the specified link.

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      return true;
  }else{
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y7FTH/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input. This just changes style of link but doesnt navigate to aspx page. :(

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/hBubq/1/

**EDIT** You might need to use an absolute URL in each of your `<a href=""` objects

```
$("li").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    window.location.href =  $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

​

```
<div id="navigation" class="right">
   <ul>
      <li id="nav1"><a href="../WebForm1.aspx"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li id="nav2"><a href="../AboutUs.aspx"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input. This navigate to aspx page but not applying style to the link. I am using absolute url now.http://localhost:36659/WebForm1.aspx

Comment: thats bc your reloading the page. u need ajax?

Comment: I dont need ajax. It is a very simple page. Just need to navigate to the page with link selected. How do i avoid reloading page here so that both works. Please help.

Comment: So you're saying that you want the link to have the active class, but you also want to load another page.

Comment: yes exactly. These links are present at header usercontrol. and when i click on that i want to change main content accordingly and also show the link with style applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().children("li").children("a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    document.location = $("a", this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your input. on click of link it navigates to 'undefined' page. I tried to check document.location url by giving an alert it shows correct url. but it navigates to http://localhost:36659/undefined and throwing error 'resource not found'.